# Storyboard - Popping to a View Controller then Pushing Causes multiple pushes

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller, unwind-segue

In Objective C / iOS;

We have a process similar to this (set up in xcode storyboard);

> *Menu View Controller* -> *Enter in a code* -> *Process/Validate* -> *Present a Failed Code page*

The (->) arrows signify a `push` segue setup in storyboard

When in failed state I want to pop to the `Enter in a code` view controller.

```
 UIViewController *vc = nil;

    NSUInteger index=0;
    for (UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SomeViewController class]]) {
            vc = viewController;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (vc) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
        });
        return;
    }
```

This pops me back to the VC I want to go to.

Except now when I press a submit on the `Enter code` page it does 3 or 4 more "pushes", when it should only be 1.

Do I need to unwind the segue?  I tried emptying the navigational view controller stack, and I even tried ridding it of its last active view controller -- both of these return a blank  or black window view frame.

Why would popping a view controller in the navigation stack affect the segues in my view controller to the point where whenever I try to do a `push segue` action it will try to push multiple view controllers onto the stack?

Comment: Where are these 3 or 4 more pushes pushing to? If you log the navigation controller's viewControllers array after these multiple pushes, what does it show you?

Comment: solved the issue. Turns out I had a button in storyboard doing a push, and then I had another push segue in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the following issue

Button press causes segue action in storyboard
I did the same segue action in code on the button, hence pushing multiple times

I have now solved this issue